# closed form expression for sum of sequence of tuples that resemble a binary counter

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, computer-science, binary

Consider a simple rule that gives a sequence of tuples. The first tuple is empty `r_0 = []`,  and subsequent tuples are obtained by finding the right-most element that is not three(insert a zero on the left if there are no elements that are not 3), incrementing that element by 1, then changing all the following elements from 3 to 2.

This is somewhat, but not quite, like a binary counter. For example, the first 50 are

```
r_0 = []
r_1 = [1]
r_2 = [2]
r_3 = [3]
r_4 = [1, 2]
r_5 = [1, 3]
r_6 = [2, 2]
r_7 = [2, 3]
r_8 = [3, 2]
r_9 = [3, 3]
r_10 = [1, 2, 2]
r_11 = [1, 2, 3]
r_12 = [1, 3, 2]
r_13 = [1, 3, 3]
r_14 = [2, 2, 2]
r_15 = [2, 2, 3]
r_16 = [2, 3, 2]
r_17 = [2, 3, 3]
r_18 = [3, 2, 2]
r_19 = [3, 2, 3]
r_20 = [3, 3, 2]
r_21 = [3, 3, 3]
r_22 = [1, 2, 2, 2]
r_23 = [1, 2, 2, 3]
r_24 = [1, 2, 3, 2]
r_25 = [1, 2, 3, 3]
r_26 = [1, 3, 2, 2]
r_27 = [1, 3, 2, 3]
r_28 = [1, 3, 3, 2]
r_29 = [1, 3, 3, 3]
r_30 = [2, 2, 2, 2]
r_31 = [2, 2, 2, 3]
r_32 = [2, 2, 3, 2]
r_33 = [2, 2, 3, 3]
r_34 = [2, 3, 2, 2]
r_35 = [2, 3, 2, 3]
r_36 = [2, 3, 3, 2]
r_37 = [2, 3, 3, 3]
r_38 = [3, 2, 2, 2]
r_39 = [3, 2, 2, 3]
r_40 = [3, 2, 3, 2]
r_41 = [3, 2, 3, 3]
r_42 = [3, 3, 2, 2]
r_43 = [3, 3, 2, 3]
r_44 = [3, 3, 3, 2]
r_45 = [3, 3, 3, 3]
r_46 = [1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
r_47 = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
r_48 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 2]
r_49 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
r_50 = [1, 2, 3, 2, 2]
```

Is it possible to find a closed-form expression for the $S_k$: the sum of the tuple `r_k`? For example, $S_6 = 2+2=4$ and $S_{10} = 1 + 2 + 2 = 5$.

This problem has arisen in some original research I am doing.

Comment: What is a three element and explainec how the rules worked to get from r_0 to r_1.

Comment: i fixed the wording slightly. by "3 element" i meant element with value 3. whenever there are no elements with value that is not 3, extend the tuple on the left by an element, set that new element to zero, then increment it by one as before

Comment: The rules now get from r0 to r1 but not from r1 to r2.

Comment: for r1, the right-most element that is not three is 1, we increment that to get 2, so r2 = [2].

Answer (score 1):

The left-most digit can be 1,2 or 3, while the remaining digits act exactly as a binary counter except with 2 and 3 instead of 0 and 1.

The length of the `r_k` tuple is given by

$$
h(k)=\left\lceil \lg\left(1+\frac{k}{3}\right)\right\rceil 
$$

It can be confirmed that the left-most digit is given by

$$
\left\lceil \frac{k-3(2^{h(k)}-1)}{2^{h(k)-1}}\right\rceil 
$$

and the remaining $h(k)-1$ digits represent the integer $k - 3[2^{h(k)}-1]$ in binary, except each digit is the bit shifted up by 2. Hence, the sum of elements of tuple $r_k$ is given by

$$
\left\lceil \frac{k-3(2^{h(k)}-1)}{2^{h(k)-1}}\right\rceil+2\left[h(k)-1\right]+\beta\left(k-3\left[2^{h(k)}-1\right]\right)
$$

where $\beta(n)$ is the sum of bits of integer $n$, and requires an $\mathcal{O}(\lg n)$ algorithm to compute using divide and conquer algorithms for Hamming-weight.